# How to read and do a min/max/avg from a NMEA stream

Tags: shell, shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have a weather station attached to my device spitting NMEA 0183 on `/tty/USB0`

I have alreeady sorted out how to parse the data and echo what I want in a script.

What I need to do now is write the `/tty/USB0` file to a file, then when I invoke my script, I want it to echo a min/max/avg for certain comma delimited fields.

Existing code:
Outputs Data from the Weather Station to a temporary file and then displays that file on screen

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -F, '/\$WIMDA/ {print $4*1000" millibars""\n" $6" Celsius""\n" $10"% Humidity""\n" "Wind Direction "$14 " Degrees""\n" "Wind Speed "$20*3.6 " km/h""\n"; fflush(); exit }' /dev/ttyUSB0 > weather1.txt
cat weather1.txt
```

I want to do this to `$6` and `$20`.

Comment: i should add my existing code

Comment: You can't average a stream.

Comment: can i take a 24h snapshot based on when the command waa invoked?

Comment: You can average a snapshot - or do a *running* average, of course. But streams can't be totally averaged while they stream - there is always some unknown value yet to come. Anyway, I would do this with `dc` rather than `awk`, but that's probably more a matter of preference than anything else.

Comment: can you plz give me an example code, based on my parameters?  i would really appreciate that

Comment: can you please give me an example code to do whatbi want?

Comment: I can't right now - on the phone, out and about. If I get back home later and you haven't any answers which look like they could work, then I'll see what I can do. You should delete at least one of those of comments - two pleases in as many seconds just looks desperate.

Comment: i deletedbthevone.  sorry.  on a tablet, not the best way to interact on here.  thought my first post did not post

Comment: no problem, i don't mind. i do this stuff for the puzzles - for the learning it earns me - and so i could care less about the asker's motives as long as the puzzle is good. but some people get kind of bent out of shape about it, and i've seen good questions downvoted to oblivion because one or two readers made some assumptions about the asker doing homework or wanting free code or whatever. i was just letting you know. by the way - i still see both comments.

Comment: sorry.  i thought i fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by timestamping the data as you receive it into a logfile:

```
awk '{print strftime("%Y.%m.%d.%H%M%S ") $0}' </tty/USB0 >>logfile
```

You can choose a format that is easy to parse. Of course, the data may already have a timestamp. 
The above gives lines with fixed width date and time beginning eg:

```
2015.07.07.093953
```

In a script you can then look through the data and extract the entries that interest you. For example
to average/max the last 24 hours use in your shell script:

```
start=$(date --date="-1 days" +"%Y.%m.%d.%H%M%S")
```

This gets the timestamp for 24 hours back in the same format. You can then get you max and average:

```
awk -v start="$start" <logfile '
$1>=start { if($7>max7)max7 = $7
            tot21 += $21+0
            numdone++
          }
END { printf "max %g, ave %g\n",max7,tot21/numdone }
'
```

Note as there is an extra field at the start of the line you need $7 now for field $6. By choosing a fixed width date format with the year first  and seconds last we can do simple string comparision between dates.